# Testing that router.navigate() has been called in a method returning an Observable<boolean>

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service which for one reason or another is accessing the router using this syntax:

```
this.injector.get( Router ).navigate( ['/login'] );
```

In the test for the `CanNavigate` method of this service, I would like to test that this `navigate()` method has been called. So, like this:

```
it( 'should navigate to login', () => {
    service.canActivate( null, null ).subscribe( ( res ) => expect( router.navigate ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( ['/login'] ));
} );
```

With that meaning anyway! This method is returning an Observable, so it's not as straightforward as this.

`fakeAsync()`?

Comment: What precisely does *"doesn't work as hoped"* mean? I would inject a mock (`{ provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter }`) instead, to avoid issues with navigation actually happening during the test (see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/14f2ffbe17727c331edf6fd0b35c4a6dce8f9153/src/app/game/actor/actor.component.spec.ts#L43).

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe, realised I was asking the wrong question and edited it quite substantially!